# Draggable Overlay Popups from DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlay

This is what I am looking for:

1. An html page includes a blank DIV (say id= "mydiv" and width is specified in style).
2. AJAX call is made to a MVC controller.  Controller returns html segment.
3. Upon return of AJAX call I want to do something like this:

   $('#mydiv').html(htmlsegment).popup();

This should cause a draggable modal dialog and display whatever html segment was returned by the controller.  Plus should have a cross in the corner to close the pupup.  Also, would be great to have a generic method to programmatically close the pupup.

I have found many examples around but they all requires doing a lot of things every time a pupup needs to be launched.  Is there an easy way using jQuery and CSS?

**EDIT 1:**

This is what I ended up using.  It works well for my requirements, except the following issue:

If I call `$self.draggable` to make the popup draggable, the close cross icon doesn't drag along. Trying to figure out how to make the icon a part of the rest of the popup so it automatically move with the moving DIV. Any ideas?

```
function xh_overlay() {
    (function ($) {

        $.fn.xhoverlay = function (options) {
            return this.each(function () {

                /*** option ***/
                var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.xhoverlay.defaults, options),
            $overlay = $('<div class="' + opts.classPrefix + '_overlay"/>'),
            $overlayClose = $('<span class="' + opts.classPrefix + '_oClose"/>'),
            $self = $(this);
                //// <reference path="../Content/images/cross.png" />

                /*** creat Dom***/
                $(opts.parent).append($self);
                $('span.' + opts.classPrefix + '_oClose').remove();
                $('body').append($overlayClose);
                //alert($overlayClose)
                $('div.' + opts.classPrefix + '_overlay').remove();
                $('body').append($overlay);


                /**** set position***/

                var topOffset = $(document).scrollTop() + 40;
                $self.show().css({ position: 'absolute', top: topOffset + 'px', padding: '12px', marginTop: 0, left: '50%', marginLeft: ($self.outerWidth() / 2) * -1, zIndex: (opts.zIndex + 2) })

               // $self.css({ 'background-color': 'Khaki', 'border-radius': '15px', border: '6px solid #FF9933', '-moz-border-radius': '15px', '-moz-box-shadow': '6px 6px 6px gray', '-webkit-border-radius': '15px', '-webkit-box-shadow': '6px 6px 6px gray', 'box-shadow': '6px 6px 6px gray', backgroundImage: 'url(' + opts.closePath + 'images/divback.jpg)' });
                $self.css({ 'background-color': 'White', 'border-radius': '12px', border: '8px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5)', '-moz-border-radius': '12px', '-webkit-border-radius': '12px', '-webkit-box-shadow': '3px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', '-moz-box-shadow': '3px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', '-o-box-shadow': '3px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', '-ms-box-shadow': '1px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', '-box-shadow': '1px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' });

                //$self.draggable();
                // set css of the overlay

                var overLH = $(window).height();
                if ($(window).height() < $(document).height())
                    overLH = $(document).height();
                $overlay
            .css({ height: overLH + 'px', position: 'absolute', width: '100%', top: 0, left: 0, zIndex: (opts.zIndex + 1), display: 'none' })
            .css({ background: opts.overlayBgCSS, opacity: opts.overlayOpCSS });

                var clPOs = $self.offset();
                $overlayClose
            .css({ position: 'absolute', 'font-size': '1px', cursor: 'pointer', padding: '12px', top: clPOs.top - 8, left: clPOs.left + $self.width() + 22, zIndex: (opts.zIndex + 3), backgroundImage: 'url(' + opts.closePath + 'images/overlaycross.png)' })

                $overlay.show();
                $overlay.fadeIn(1, function () {
                    $self.show(); opts.onLoad();
                });

                $(window).resize(setOverlayHeight).resize(setSelfPosition)
                //.scroll(setSelfPosition)
                // $self.find(opts.closeSelector).add($overlay).click(function() { closeXhoverlay(); return false; });
                $self.find(opts.closeSelector).add($overlayClose).click(function () { closeXhoverlay(); return false; });
                $self.bind('close', closeXhoverlay);
                $self.bind('resize', setSelfPosition);


                function closeXhoverlay() {
                    $self.html("");
                    $self.hide();
                    $overlay.remove();
                    $overlayClose.remove();
                    opts.onClose();
                    //$self.html("");
                }

                function setOverlayHeight() {
                    if ($(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                        $overlay.css({ height: $(document).height() + 'px' });
                    }
                }

                function setSelfPosition() {
                    var topOffset = $(document).scrollTop() + 40;
                    $self.css({ top: topOffset + 'px' });
                    var clPOs = $self.offset();
                    $overlayClose.css({ top: clPOs.top - 10, left: clPOs + $self.width() + 15 });
                }

            });
        }

        $.fn.xhoverlay.defaults = {
            // close
            closeSelector: ".close",
            closeClick: true,
            closeEsc: true,
            closePath: 'Content/',
            effect: 'apple',

            // callbacks
            onLoad: function () { },
            onClose: function () { },

            // style
            classPrefix: 'xh',
            zIndex: 999,
            centered: false,
            modalCSS: { top: '40px' },

            overlayBgCSS: '#ddd',
            overlayOpCSS: .6,
            //overlayCSS: { background: this.overlayBgCSS, opacity: this.overlayOpCSS },
            parent: 'body'
        }
        //$.fn.xhoverlay.defaults.overlayCSS = { background: $.fn.xhoverlay.defaults.overlayCSS.overlayBgCSS, opacity: $.fn.xhoverlay.defaults.overlayCSS.overlayOpCSS }


    })(jQuery);
}

$(document).ready(function() { xh_overlay(); })
```

Comment: trying to do a fiddle. But draggable doesn't work and the close icon doesn't show.  Both works ok in my app.  http://jsfiddle.net/3qL9J/2/

Comment: correction: except that icon doesn't drag with the div.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right way: such components exists in jQuery UI, see samples here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

That's called a `dialog`, detailed here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

In your case, you can call the `dialog` method when you receive your Ajax response. If you need to customize the dialog there are several options.

Sample for a div with an "OK" button that will close the dialog on click:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).dialog({
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
     Ok: function() {
       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes this will work, with "width:auto" in the options. Only issue is that I am using a jQuery UI theme that looks very good for option buttons, etc. but I don't like that color on the popups :-).  If nothing else work, I will live with it. Thanks.

Comment: You can also customize the colors with jQuery Theme Roller.

Answer (score 0):

How do you feel about plugins? [Here's](http://www.ajaxshake.com/demo/EN/974/2ecb9fe8/draggable-windows-with-prototype-and-scriptaculous-draggablewindows.html) a plugin link

IF not try this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $$('#mydiv').makeDraggable({});
});
```

Hope this helps